# GAE migration to HRD. Possible to go back?

Tags: google-app-engine, migration, google-cloud-datastore

I migrated a project to HRD using the migration tool.

This seems to have various side effects. Some might be related to unanchored entities or queries. The app doesn't send the notification emails it is supposed to which may have something to do with Billing needed to be re-enabled and Google waiting seven days before applying mail quota.

Anyways, I am wondering if it is possible to roll back to master/slave? Disable or delete the HRD app and re-enable the old one?

As a way for me to buy time, prepare better for this migration and try again at a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't go back because Master/Slave Datatsore is [deprecated since April 4, 2012](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/usingmasterslave). You could contact the support, but I would suggest you to spend some time and try to fix it on HRD.